# Debian's GNOME 3: remove users from login menu

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, gnome3, users

I have upgraded to Debian Wheezy from Squeeze and all users, including system ones, such as `qmail` are visible on the GNOME 3's greeter. How do I hide them from this login menu?

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/gdm3/greeter.gsettings` file uncomment the following  line:

```
disable-user-list=true
```

Then restart `gdm3` service. In Debian Jessie it's `sudo systemctl restart gdm3.service` and in earlier versions of Debian it is `sudo service gdm3 restart`.

This will disable user selector in login menu. You'll be forced to enter username and password every time you get here, unless you set up autologin.

Comment: Upvoted. Works in Debian 8.1 Jessie's `Gnome 3` too.

Answer (score 1):

In DEBIAN 12 BOOKWORM, ENABLING the dconf setting
org/gnome/login-screen/disable-user-list
does not work as it did in Debian 11.

THE FILE TO EDIT IN DEBIAN 12 BOOKWORM:

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults
```

Uncomment the line (ENABLING "disable"):

```
disable-user-list=true
```

Then restart. This will disable the User Menu list in the GDM3 login, and prompt for a Username and Password at every login, unless Auto-login is enabled. Upgrading from Debian 11 to 12 apparently leaves some deprecated legacy settings.

Comment: Oops, did not expect run-on lines, and don't know how to fix. Please delete this post. Don't see how to do that either.